# Use of << and >>> in a hash function

Tags: java, c, hash, hashcode

I have a project in C where I need to created a suitable hash function for void pointers which could contain alphanumeric chars, ints or just plain ol' chars.

I need to use a polynomial hash fuction, where instead of multiplying by a constant, I should use a cyclic shift of partial sums by a fixed number of bits. 
In this page [here](https://www.cpp.edu/~ftang/courses/CS240/lectures/hashing.htm)
, there's the java code(I assume this is java because of the use of strings):

```
static int hashCode(String s) {
  int h = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    h = (h << 5) | (h >>> 27); // 5-bit cyclic shift of the running sum
    h += (int) s.charAt(i); // add in next character
  }
  return h;
}
```

What exactly is this line, below, doing?

```
h = (h << 5) | (h >>> 27); // 5-bit cyclic shift of the running sum
```

Yes, the comment says 5bit cyclic shift, but how does the `<<`, `|` and `>>>` operands work in this regard? I've never seen or used any of them before.

Comment: What kind of research have you done to try and learn what those operators* do?

Comment: `(h >>> 27)` are you sure?

Comment: @AlterMann Why do you ask, it seems perfectly legit? Altogether it's ROTL 5.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, is not valid in C, thats why I am asking

Comment: @AlterMann straight from the linked page.

Comment: @AlterMann I guess you didn't expect to find a difference between Java and C at this level. But actually `>>>` is the "C" shift and `>>` is Java's special thing related to "everything is signed" and keeping the equivalence of shifting and exponentiation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, there are tons of code typedefing String to `char *` cs50.h is one of them, but thank you for pointing that

Comment: @AlterMann It's `string` actually and that was my main point---isn't camelCase an eyesore for a C guy?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I've noticed a lot of C programmers prefer to not use camelCase, even my project spec forbids it.

Comment: Exactly, in C it is somewhat of an anathema, unless you're on Windows of course.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, you are right, is often in lowercase

Answer (score 4):

As it says, it's a 5-bit cyclic left shift. This means that all the bits are shifted left, with the bit "shifted off" added to the right side, five times.

The code replaces the value of `h` with the value of two bit patterns ORed together. The first bit pattern is the original value shifted left 5 bits. The second value is the original value shifted right 27 bits.

The left shift of 5 bits puts all the bits but the leftmost five in their final position. The leftmost 5 bits get "shifted out" by that shift and replaced with zeroes as the rightmost bits of the output. The right shift of 27 bits put the leftmost five bits in their final position as the rightmost bits, shifting in zeroes for the leftmost 27 bits. ORing them together produces the desired output.

The `>>>` is Java's [unsigned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) shift operation. In C or C++, you'd just use `>>`.

Comment: `h >>> 27` doesn't seems a value shifted, typo?

Comment: @AlterMann `>>>` is the "zero fill right shift" operator in Java.

Comment: No, it is not a typo. `>>>` is the "regular" shift right and `>>` is the sign-extending right shift, which you definitely do not want here.

Comment: @IanAbbott Is it a typo? or it the "zero fill right shift" required here as Ian suggests?

Comment: So in c, would the equivalent to java's :
h = (h << 5) | (h >>> 27) 
be:
h = (h << 5) | (h >> 27);

Comment: @Monkleys Zero filling on the right is definitely required here.

Comment: @Monkleys Yes, the equivalent in C would be `h = (h << 5) | (h >> 27);` as long as `h` has an exactly 32-bit, unsigned integer type, such as `uint32_t`.

Comment: @IanAbbott what would be the significance of me using:
h = (h << 7) | (h >>> 13);
Would it make a significant difference in the final hash using these primes instead?

Comment: A plain `unsigned int` would do for `h` as long as you carefully mask off bits 32 and above after each step. E.g. `h = ((h << 5)  | (h >> 27)) & 0xffffffffu;`.

Comment: @Monkleys It's not about primes, it's about implementing ROTL as two shifts. Whereas 5 + 27 is 32, 7 + 13 isn't. And generally, the most crucial point in hash implementation is preserving as much information as possible. ROTL is perfectly information-preserving, whereas your arbitrary combination of shifts isn't.

Comment: @Monkleys Since that's not a cyclic shift, it would make a huge difference.

Comment: My earlier comment "_A plain `unsigned int` would do for `h` ..._" is clearly wrong if `unsigned int` is less than 32-bits wide. Assuming current C standards are implemented, `uint32_t` might not be implemented on weird systems, but `uint_least32_t` will be implemented, so that can be used as long as you mask off bits 32 and above at each step, like I showed for `unsigned int`.